# Setting python path for testing in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently my vscode is using global python path in pyenv to discover the pytest test.
The problem is I don't want vscode to use global python path for testing, I want it to use my virtual python environment ( for consistency ).

Is there a way to configure visual code to use custom python environment?

[image]

^ This is the function of visual code I am talking about.

I have tried to the setting.json file but I haven't see anything there.

Edit: Thank you everyone, you are, the python environment for testing is actually same as workspace python environment. So you just have to change the workspace environment in: "Python select interpreter". The testing tool is using that environment, cheers.

Comment: Check out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: +1 what Dan said. VSCode normally does a pretty good job detecting your virtual environment if it's in your current working directory. If it does not, I usually use cmd+shift+p and select the "Python: Select Interpreter" command to enter the path manually (assuming you have the Python extension installed)

Comment: Same error. I printed `print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))` right from `conftest.py`. And the result is `/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.18.0/pythonFiles`. I also use env file in my tests launch config, which is set like this 
`...
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/launch.env",
...
`
All other vars from that launch.env file are set correctly, except python patch which is locked to extension folder

Comment: *except PYTHONPATH. Please let me know if smb find a decision

Comment: Why is there no simple function to set the PYTHONPATH to include the current folder so that tests may be run properly? Is this a bug or missing feature request?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension installed. If so, install it. Then you will find the option to change the python path. Please check the *Set up your environment* section in the extensions page for how to do that.